# Is the sentence "I got enthusiastic" grammatically correct and commonly used?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, clauses

Can we use `got` in this case? Is it right and usual?

> after that meeting I got enthusiastic about traveling

Comment: Say, why do you think we can't?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. But many would say it's a bit more "informal" than synonymous ***became***.

Comment: Tnx, cuz I search it on the Google and I didn't find any convincing result.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, "**got**" is appropriate to use.

> I **got** enthusiastic
>   I **got** tired
>   I **got** hungry

has more a feeling of a *quick change*, in contrast to

> I **became** enthusiastic
>   I **became** tired
>   I **became** hungry

The common phrase

> I **got** it!

is often used to signify grabbing/grasping something quickly, like an idea, in a "*light bulb moment*"

Answer (score 3):

> I got enthusiastic about travelling.

The above sentence is correct grammatically.

You can use the verb `get` as a linking verb in the sense of becoming; it links the subject (l) of the sentence with the adjective enthusiastic. Some examples are:

> He is getting ready.
>   It's getting late.
>   I got tired when I was working in the garden.
>   It's got dark now.

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that "gotten" is an alternative past participle to "got," Americans will usually say "It's gotten dark now," while British usually prefer "got".

Comment: @BobRodes, I think Americans don't use gotten as a linking verb.

Comment: I'm an American, and I do. I would say that it has gotten dark, for example.